# multiple chartjs in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, charts

hi i was trying to use chartjs 
can be found in this link [www.chartjs.org](http://www.chartjs.org)

i tried to draw two chart in the same page using the samples code

i created two different div with two different ids

like this

```
<div id="chart1"></div>
<div id="chart2"></div>
```

then after including this line :

i created the first chart this way:

```
 window.onload = function(){
    var ctx1 = document.getElementById("chart1").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx1).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive: true
    });
}
```

and the second chart this way :

```
   window.onload = function(){
        var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart2").getContext("2d");
        window.myPie = new Chart(ctx2).Pie(pieData);
    };
```

data used for both chart is the same like as samples , so nothing changed
but if i draw just one chart by itself it works great
if i put the two chart at the same time i get only the pie chart

can you tell me where is the problem please
i think it is some sort of conflict , but i can't find it

Answer (score 32):

Use only one window.onload

```
window.onload = function () {
        window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d")).Radar(radarChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });
        var G2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(G2).Bar(barChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });
    }
```

Comment: If you have PHP code in between your two charts for e.g. and you move the closing `}` of the `window.onload = function() ` at the end of your PHP code. It doesn't seem to like this and no longer shows the charts, any idea how to get around that?

Answer (score 6):

I have not worked on different type of charts but I worked on an example and created two bar chart in a page using this code:

```html
<div style="width: 50%">
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
</div>

<div style="width: 50%">
    <canvas id="canvas2" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
</div>
```

and in script part I do like this:

```javascript
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};

var barChartData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        }
    ]

}
    var barChartData2 = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        }
    ]

}
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive : true
    });
    var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx2).Bar(barChartData2, {
        responsive : true
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First off, you only need one window.onload event.  No reason to have two separate instances of that.

Second, the data sets for Pie chart and Line chart are actually very different.

Pie chart sample data:

```
        self.pieData=  [
        {
            value: 65,
            color:"#F7464A",
            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
            label: "New Scenarios"
        },
        {
            value: 297,
            color: "#46BFBD",
            highlight: "#5AD3D1",
            label: "Responses Submitted"
        },
        {
            value: 225,
            color: "#64a789",
            highlight: "#5AD3D1",
            label: "Responses Graded"
        }

    ]
```

Line chart sample data:

```
self.lineData= {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "New Tests",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "#64a789",
            pointColor: "#64a789",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "Responses",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [128, 148, 140, 119, 186, 127, 190]
        },
        {
            label: "Responses Graded",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "#41e498",
            pointColor: "#41e498",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [108, 116, 120, 112, 136, 121, 111]
        }
    ]
};
```

The line chart is likely not initializing because you are feeding it the wrong kind of data.

Answer (score 4):

Use only 1 window.onload

```
function myfunc1{
}
function myfunc2{
}
function start(){
myfunc1();
myfunc1();
}
window.onload = start();
```

Ref: 
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3724571/Using-Multiple-JavaScript-Onload-Functions.htm

Answer (score -1):

I try this code ... this solve your problem

```
 var barChartData = {
            labels: [<?php echo $str_indiv_value; ?>],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Dataset 1',
                backgroundColor: [
                    window.chartColors.red,
                    window.chartColors.orange,
                    window.chartColors.yellow,
                    window.chartColors.green,
                    window.chartColors.blue,
                    window.chartColors.purple,
                    window.chartColors.red
                ],
                yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
                data: [
                   <?php echo $str_indiv_requred;?>
                ]
            }]

        };

        var barChartData_2 = {
            labels: [<?php echo $str_indiv_value; ?>],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Dataset 1',
                backgroundColor: [
                    window.chartColors.red,
                    window.chartColors.orange,
                    window.chartColors.yellow,
                    window.chartColors.green,
                    window.chartColors.blue,
                    window.chartColors.purple,
                    window.chartColors.red
                ],
                yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
                data: [
                    <?php echo $str_indiv_requred;?>
                ]
            }]

        };


        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartData,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Multi Axis'
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: true
                    },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            type: 'linear', // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                            display: true,
                            position: 'left',
                            id: 'y-axis-1',
                        }],
                    }
                }
            });




            var ctx_2 = document.getElementById('canvas2').getContext('2d');
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx_2, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartData_2,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Multi Axis'
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: true
                    },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            type: 'linear', // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                            display: true,
                            position: 'left',
                            id: 'y-axis-1',
                        }],
                    }
                }
            });



        };
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to the code in the body of your answer?

Answer (score -3):

You could rather user jQuery to get the canvas object

```
var ctx = $parent.find('#' + idOfCanvas).get(0).getContext("2d");
```

now make sure the code below is not throwing js error at all

```
window.onload = function(){
        var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart2").getContext("2d");
        window.myPie = new Chart(ctx2).Pie(pieData);
    };
```

as you know, if any error in js occurs the js-runtime halts all the latter lines of code